# Combinations in forming a function

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How many different ways are there to form a function $f:X\rightarrow Y$ if $|X| = a$ and $|Y| = b$

Surjective function?

Bijective function?

Injective function?

I have so far: There are $a!$ ways to form a bijective function. As $a=b$ the answer can also be written as $b!$.

There are $x$ number of ways to form a surjective function if $a=b$. $x$ is number of ways to form a bijective functions plus all the non-injecive functions. For the final answer, I must add combinations if $b=a-1$, $b=a-2$, ... , $b=1$.

There are $\frac{b!}{(b-a)!}$ possibilities in forming injective function.

I think there are $a^b$ possible ways to form a function between those two sets.

I could use some help. Thanks.

Comment: See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/572049/14366) by Brian M. Scott.

Comment: ... so you're guessing there are infinitely many functions $\{1\}\to\{5\}$, for example? Show two, please.

Comment: I understand my mistake. I'll edit my first post...

Answer (score 1):

Hint (more of a solution) for surjective: If $a < b$ then it's hopeless, so the answer is none. Now, if $a \geq b$, we can count thusly: let there be $b$ boxes (the elements of $Y$). What we are they trying to count is the number of ways to put $a$ distinguishable items in $b$ distinguishable boxes, such that each box has at least one item in it. Let's reduce to a simpler problem, one with distinguishable boxes. If we have that result, call it $k$, then we can make the boxes distinguishable by adding a factor of $b!$, which we pick up by permuting the labels of the boxes. The number of ways to do this is known as a Stirling number, $S(a,b)$. Its derivation is nontrivial.

Hint for injective: If $a > b$ then again the answer is none. If not, then choose $a$ elements from $Y$ to map to, then notice that a map from $X$ to those $a$ elements is uniquely defined by an ordering of those $a$ elements (put the elements of $X$ in a line, and write their images under $f$ above them, for instance).

Hint for bijective: If $a \neq b$ then we're lost, so assume $a = b$. Use the ordering argument for counting the number of injective functions, but this time there's no need to choose any $a$ elements, because you need to hit all of them and $a = b$.

As for all functions, you are close, but your formula is not correct. For instance, if $X = \{0\}$ and $Y = \{0,1\}$ then there are clearly two maps, whereas your formula gives one. Consider the sets $X = \{0,1\}, Y = \{0,1,2\}$. How many maps are there? First you need to select $f(0)$, for which there are three options, then $f(1)$, for which there are three options as well. Altogether, how many maps are there? $3 \times 3 = 9$. Try to generalize this.

Comment: is the answer to number of injective functions $b^a$?

Comment: What about if $a=0$ or $b=0$? Should I also point out that if neither of the sets are empty, then there are no functions to form.

Comment: To your first comment, yes, that is the answer. Just treat $a = 0$ and $b = 0$ as special cases; you're right, there aren't functions in that case.

Comment: If $a=0$ then there is exactly one function, the _empty function_. It is always injective but surjective (if and) only if $b=0$. This is not a special case!

Comment: Also, the "surjective" hint will lead to many functions being double counted. It's not clear that there's any easy way to correct for this.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I apologize, yes, I always forget about the empty function. I'll correct the surjective hint now.

Comment: The [Wikipedia article for the relevant kind of Stirling number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind) gives an explicit formula that includes a $\frac{1}{b!}$ ready to cancel out. The rest of it (which is the answer sought here) looks like it should be derivable with an inclusion-exclusion argument directly.